# Google Spreadsheet 'Countunique' Returns 1 or 0

Tags: google-sheets

I have date data in rows in Sheet 1. Then, I want to count days with a range in another sheet (Sheet 2), with the `countunique` formula.

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFWW1.png)

[tombol tanggal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzIwD.png)

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCuzf.png)

I use the following formula in cell B3: `=countunique(filter('Sheet 1'!A2:A9, 'Sheet 1'!A2:A9>=B1, 'Sheet 1'!A2:A9<=B2))`

But the result is 1, whereas the result should be 4, not 1.

However, if I input the value manually in Sheet 2 B1:B2 (not the value from Sheet 1), the results is correct: 4.

[Sheet 2 with manual input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z8bb.png)

Please, help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: it's hard to troubleshoot an issue only by looking at some screenshot. Would it be possible to share your spreadsheet with editing rights?

Comment: Dear @JPV, thanks for your advice. But, alhamdulillah, it was solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to set the criteria for a date range (Numeric) with values that are Text. If so, try wrapping `B1` and `B2` in your UNIQUE formula with `VALUE(   )`,

Comment: Dear @pnuts.

You are so great. It really works. Thank you very much.